# DialogflowからGoogle spread sheetを読み書きしたい

Tags: google-api, dialogflow

こちらに質問するのが妥当かどうかもまだわかってない初心者です。
Google Home ＋ Dialogflowを使って、それぞれの利用者のGoogle DriveにあるGoogle spread sheetを読み書きしたいです。
ユーザ認証含めてどうしたらよいのかわかりません。
これを実現するには、何を使ってどういう構成にするのがよいでしょうか？
こういう質問ができる場所や参考になるURLなど教えて頂けたらありがたいです。
うまく説明できなくてあいまいな質問ですがよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

全部を細かく説明すると大長編になりそうなので、実現可能と思われる処理フローを紹介してみます。

1. DialogflowのFulfillmentとして、Google Cloud FunctionsのＵＲＬを登録しておく。
2. Actions on Googleの[Account Linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking)や`Sign in required for welcome intent`を使って、Googleアカウントを特定する。
3. Google Spreadsheet API v4をCloud FunctionsのGCPプロジェクトで利用可能にしておく。
4. サービスアカウントを発行し、操作したいGoogle Spreadsheetに共有しておく。
5. Fulfillmentのコード内でSpreadsheet APIを使って、読み書きを行う。

構成図としては、以下となると思います。

```
AoG <-> Dialogflow <-> Cloud Functions <-> Spreadsheet API <-> Spreadsheet
```

ご参考になると幸いです。

Comment: こんにちは。「Actions on GoogleのAccount LinkingやSign in required for welcome intent」いう考えは自分の中になかったので参考になりました。時間がかかるかもしれませんが調べながら作成してみます。
ＰＳ．いつもご活躍見ております。今後のご確約期待しております。